# User Information using cookies/session in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, session, cookie

I am working on a Magento extension. In this extension I would like that user can add products from front side. Those products will be shown on his account when is logged in or not. If the user is not registered he can save his information and when he logges in he can view all his products (For not logged in user see only his current products).

I can use custom php cookies for that for guest, but I don't think it's the best way, because I know Magento stores guest information in the session.
I want to use Magento user cookies functionality for that, How can I do that. Only the user handling part.

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Focus on the content from the second paragraph with code-related inquiry e.g. "how do I access cookies via the framework" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user session data can be retrieved (and set) whether a use is logged in or not using

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session",  array("name"=>"frontend"));

$session->setData('foo', 'bar');
echo $session->getData('foo'); // bar
```

It sounds like you want to make an extension similar to the wish list functionality in Magento. Perhaps it would be a good idea to first take a look at that extension if it fits your requirements.

If you do want to make an extension like this I suggest creating a dedicated table for it in the database storing the product ID and either the logged in customer ID or the session ID.
Take a look at the following [tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table) on working with tables in your custom extension.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Regarding to tutorial i know how to work with custom tables.Already done many extensions.I think getting visitor information using Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getVisitorData() returns more data for information.But the problem is visitor id changes everty time user loggedin or out.

Comment: True, that's why the Magento wish list extension is only available for logged in users. Even cookies would not help you here as they are only valid for so long.